# How to run powershell script using c# in SharePoint solution

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i am getting below error while i am trying to run power-shell script in my SharePoint solution

> The type initializer for
>   'System.Management.Automation.SessionStateScope' threw an exception.

just a reference

```
private void RunPowershellScript(string scriptFile, List<string> parameters)
{
    PowerShell OPowerShell = null;
    Runspace OSPRunSpace = null;

    try
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration OSPRSConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        PSSnapInException OExSnapIn = null;

        //Add a snap in for SharePoint. This will include all the power shell commands for SharePoint
        PSSnapInInfo OSnapInInfo = OSPRSConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell", out OExSnapIn);

        OSPRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(OSPRSConfiguration);

        OPowerShell = PowerShell.Create();

        OPowerShell.Runspace = OSPRunSpace;

        Command Cmd1 = new Command("backup-spsite");
        Cmd1.Parameters.Add("identity", "Your Site Coll URL");
        Cmd1.Parameters.Add("path", "Back up file path");



        OPowerShell.Commands.AddCommand(Cmd1 );

        OSPRunSpace.Open();

        OPowerShell.Invoke();

        OSPRunSpace.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        //Handle exception
    }
    finally
    {
        if (OSPRunSpace != null)
        {
            OSPRunSpace.Dispose();
            OSPRunSpace = null;
        }

        if (OPowerShell != null)
        {
            OPowerShell.Dispose();
            OPowerShell = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: Can you check what the inner exception is please it might give a further explanation as to why

Comment: in the web.config file

change the legacyCasModel to "false" in the below tag

<trust level="Full" originUrl="" legacyCasModel="true" />

Comment: can you please give me a sample so i can refer that because right now i dont have any web.config file in my solution